# PHP Infinite script with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table users that I need to upload continuously, so once updated, I would like to relaunch the command directly.

Actually, I'm using a cron that launch itself each minute with Laravel (`$schedule->command('update:users')->everyMinute();`), but I'm losing some time if the job is quicker than one minute of I will overload my server if it is more than one minute.

I was thinking to maybe use a queue, and once the script terminated, relauch itself, like this:

```
// Do My stuff
Queue::push(new UpdateUsers($));
```

But if the script crash, it will not reload itself, and I need to launch it at least once. I know that I could use a pcntl_fork function, but I would like to have a turnkey function with Laravel. How should I do ?

Comment: Can't you just put the whole command in a `while(true){})` loop and run it once?

Comment: A note: you can prevent overloading your server with `withoutOverlapping()` - it'll ensure no more than one copy of the script runs at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest running a Command the Cli,
in the command place a

```
while (true)
```

loop so it will run forever. After you created this script you can run it with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

this service runs the command you tell him, and when it fails it will relaunch it automaticlly. Just be aware that after X failures it will stop, it depends on how you configured it.

Example for conf file in:

```
/etc/supervisord/conf.d/my_infinite_script.conf
```

and contents could be:

```
[program:laravel_queue]
command=php artisan your_command:here
directory=/path/to/laravel
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/your_command.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/your_command.out.log
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used the approach suggested by Tzook Bar Noy in some cases, but have also used a slightly uglier method which can avoid issues with having scripts looping forever if this might cause problems. This can be called every minute in a cronjob:

```
$runForSeconds = 55;
$runMinute = date('i');
do {
    ....code....
} while (date('i') == $runMinute && intval(date('s')) < $runForSeconds);
```

But the best solution would be to use a Jobs queue and run that using supervisor and:

```
command=php artisan queue:listen
```